# CLion: Issues Integrating graphics.h

Tags: c++, installation, graphics, clion, libs

How can I connect graphics.h to my C Lion project. I've been trying for days, but it's not working. Who has experience in this, please help (I'm probably too dumb for this)

I tried to add the graphics.h file and its associated files to the mingw compiler itself, which is in CLion, but nothing worked. I also tried to add locally to the project, but still nothing came out.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about the problem you are having. Is the compiler not finding the file? Do you have a different compile error? A linker error? What specifically have you done that hasn't worked?

Comment: Do you realise that `graphics.h` is only a header file? And that for it to work you also need the associated library file?

Comment: In any case you need to say exactly what you have done, and exactly what problem you see, and also the code you are using. There's nowhere near enough information here for anyone to be able to help except by pointing you at documentation.

Comment: I added everything I needed, the file is located, but Clean cannot compile. Mainly due to the fact that it does not find the library that I have explicitly added

Comment: I have added graphics header files.h and winbgim.h to the include folder, as well as the libbgi.a and graphics.lib libraries to the libs folder. the following error pops up

These errors seem to be related to unresolved references to functions like initwindow, circle, and closegraph. I have properly included the graphics.h and graphics.lib files in my project. What could be causing these undefined reference errors, and how can I resolve them?